# Call external REST Web Service from Conversation API

Tags: node.js, rest

I need to forward the user input to an external web service and feed Watson with the response from this service.

I have pushed the sample code from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple and added the node-rest-client from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client . I have created the respective service and binded it so that the Chat Application works properly.

When I however add the code

```
    client.get("https://<my domain>.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/api/service/" + payload.input.text, function(data, response)) {
        payload.input.text = data.message;  
    }
```

the application can not be started and I get the error that the deployment has FAILED at STAGING.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the `<my-domain>` part of the request string?

Also, are you sure that callback is correct? Typically, node callbacks accept an error as their first parameter and pass their data later parameters.

You could try to run `cf logs` or go to your bluemix portal and get the more in-depth logs. They probably contain the line that fails, with a more detailed exception.

Another issue might be that you're seemingly updating a global variable inside of an asynchronous callback. This is not a good idea! Make sure you understand async. I'd reccomend https://nodeschool.io/

Staging errors are also sometimes incurred by not updating your dependencies. Make sure to install with `npm install --save` so that your `package.json` gets updated

Would be good if you could setup a repo with the *complete* code you're working with. That makes it way easier for us to debug